# Pick one cell of row within every groupby with all different combinations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
   a  b  c
1  0  1  None
2  0  1  2
3  0  3  None
4  1  2  None
```

For every group of 'a' I need to pick one cell of columns b, c, ...
The desired output is:

```
   a  prod
1  0  1  
   0  1  
   0  3  
2  0  1
   0  2
   0  3
1  1  2
```

Therefore I did:

```
[In:] 
x=df.iloc[0].values
y=df.iloc[1].values
z=df.iloc[2].values

[Out:]

x: [1, None]
y: [1, 2]
z: [3, None]

[In:]

x1 = list(filter(None, x))
x2 = list(filter(None, y))
x3 = list(filter(None, z))

a=[x1, y1, z1]

prod=list(it.product(*a))

[Out:]

[(1, 1, 3),(1, 2, 3)]
```

which is looking like the desired part of the column.
But in this case I only get the desired output for the first group of 'a'. How can I transfer this to all groups of a?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, got a solution for you.

First, we make some sample data.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],
    'b': [random.choice([None] + list(range(5))) for _ in range(10)],
    'c': [random.choice([None] + list(range(5))) for _ in range(10)],
})

print(df)
```

**Outputs**

```
   a  b    c
0  0  1  NaN
1  0  3  0.0
2  0  4  1.0
3  1  0  3.0
4  1  1  3.0
5  1  2  4.0
6  1  0  4.0
7  1  0  4.0
8  2  1  1.0
9  2  0  2.0
```

Then, this should solve your problem.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

prods = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda group: list(it.product(
    *[list(it.filterfalse(np.isnan, row)) for row in zip(group.b, group.c)])))
pd.DataFrame(prods)
```

**Outputs**

```
                                                    0
a                                                   
0  [(1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 1.0), (1, 0.0, 4), (1, 0.0,...
1  [(0, 1, 2, 0, 0), (0, 1, 2, 0, 4.0), (0, 1, 2,...
2           [(1, 0), (1, 2.0), (1.0, 0), (1.0, 2.0)]
```

**Old answer**

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 1],
    'b': [1, 1, 3, 2],
    'c': [None, 2, None, None]
})

prod = df.groupby('a').prod()
print(prod)
```

**Output**

```
   b    c
a        
0  3  2.0
1  2  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By product(), I mean the combinations of the, in this case, three lists. If you look at my output, it's what I need for every group in 'a'.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure what you mean. In your desired output, what determines why there are three rows with index 1, three with index 2, zero with index 3 and one with index 4? And what exactly do you mean by combination? Are you trying to sum a, b, and c, multiply them, or?

Comment: the index doesn't really matter. I don't want any mathematical operation. If you look into row 1, 'b' and 'c' have one value within columns 'b' and 'c'. In row 2 two values and row 3 one value. I want to combine these. The 2 possible ways to combine these three rows are the tuples (1,1,3) and (1,2,3). The first tuperl picks the value of column 'b' and the second from column 'c'. Does it get any clearer?

Comment: Are they always going to be tuples of length 3? Edit: I get it now, you want one from each row.

Comment: exactly. The length can be from 1 to 4, depending on the amount of rows of each group. They vary between 1 and 4.

Comment: Updated my answer, I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: looks good, thank you very much. Now I only need this output in a dataframe with my column 'a'. Something with tolist() and stack() maybe?

Comment: Updated to put output in dataframe.